# How to stream local video using Django

Tags: python, django, video-streaming

I’m using [python-ffmpeg-video-streaming](https://github.com/hadronepoch/python-ffmpeg-video-streaming) in my Django project. I can able to generate mpd and m3u8 files successfully, but I didn’t know how to serve these file using Django views.

I tried this approach, but this is not working:

```
def stream_multi_quality_video(request):
    video_path = "./dashpath/dash.mpd"

    with open(video_path, "rb") as mpd_file:
        mpd_contents = mpd_file.read()
    # Set the response headers
    response = HttpResponse(mpd_contents, content_type="application/dash+xml")
    response["Content-Length"] = len(mpd_contents)
    return response
```

After this, I got a "chunk file not found" error in the browser console.

Here is my frontend code for videojs:

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
           data-setup="{}">
        <source src="{% url 'stream_video' %}" type="application/dash+xml">
    </video>
</div>

<script>
    var player = videojs('my-video');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you taking? If 404, I think it should be mistake in the URL.

Usually on taking media, you should use statics:

```
<source src="{% static '<media_dir_path>/stream_video' %}" type="application/dash+xml">
```